# jarsigner "Only one alias can be specified"

Tags: jarsigner

In Windows command prompt:

```
>keytool -genkey -alias me
>keytool -selfcert -alias me
>jarsigner myJar.jar me
Only one alias can be specified
```

I have failed to find any info on this error on the web. I'm obviously only specifying one alias here. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: It seems that the error is displayed if there are other parameters not starting with dash that the jar and alias: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:WriOTi-nGrUJ:www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/security/tools/JarSigner.html+&cd=8&hl=fi&ct=clnk&gl=fi&client=firefox-a Your input seems correct.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I was getting the same error.

I resolved it by renaming the folders in my path

```
c:\this is a folder\ replaced with c:\this_is_a_folder\
```

jarsigner doesn't like spaces in folders

Comment: I never use spaces in any workspace directory. Still get the problem.

Comment: Need more information to solve this, what is the command you are using? This particular problem was related to something similar to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\bin>jarsigner.exe -verbose -storetype pkcs12 -keystore e:\mk_ca.pfx -tsa http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timestamp.dll -storepass password "E:\wamp\www\app\test.jar" "keyblahblahblah123"`

Comment: jarsigner never even sees the spaces in folders. It is the *command shell* that doesn't understand them. You need to quote arguments with spaces in them, to *any* program. Nothing to do with jarsigner whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

Just put quotes around the filename(s) with spaces. You need to quote arguments with spaces in them, to any program. Nothing to do with jarsigner whatsoever.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the space from Folder Name like

jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.jks **D:\AndroidProject\CheckFinalCodeNew\CheckFinalCode\platforms\android\build\outputs\apk\android-release-unsigned.apk** my-alias

The problem would be resolve

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error even though I had put quotes around my paths, and also when I moved everything to a folder name with no spaces at. The spaces in the path turned out to be a [Red Herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).

Confusingly, Jarsigner would work from a Command Prompt window, but not from Powershell, the Windows Terminal app, or an Ant Task (using an `exec` job).

Turns out I'd copied and pasted the basic Jarsigner command from a PDF, and **one of the hyphens in the command wasn't a real hyphen**, but some Unicode doppelganger.

(I probably ought to let @mark-rabjohn write this up and get the credit, as it was his brainwave to check it was all ASCII, but as this wasted six hours of my life I'm just not feeling that generous.)

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the whitespaces that caused the same error.

My previous CLI command was

```bash
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ${KEYSTORE_FILE} ${UNSIGNED_APK} key0
```

Then I wrapped my variables with double quotes which solved my problem

```bash
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "${KEYSTORE_FILE}" "${UNSIGNED_APK}" key0
```

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem and solved it by switching to jarsigner from jdk 6. Although I created my cert with keytool from jdk 7, I could not sign it with its jarsigner.

Comment: Who is downvoting my answer and why? Check other comments to see there are other users that had this issue without space related folder names etc. This was a working solution for me at this time.