# jarsigner “Only one alias can be specified”

Tags: android, android-keystore

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin> jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore Cartoons.keystore Cartoons.apk Cartoons
```

When I run this command I get this error:
Only one alias can be specified

Comment: possible duplicate of [jarsigner "Only one alias can be specified"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748089/jarsigner-only-one-alias-can-be-specified)

Answer (score 1):

One way is to rename your path to remove the spaces, so:

`C:\a folder with spaces\` should be replaced with `C:\a_folder_with_spaces\`

Or in your case

```
C:\Program_Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin
```

As pointed out in the comments, the alternative is to specify a full path to the keystore and the apk file, and put quotes around them: ( *Although I don't claim to have tested this.. Presumably EJP, who pointed this out, has* )

```
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore "C:/Program Files/..../Cartoons.keystore" "C:/Program Files/...../Cartoons.apk" "C:/Program Files/..../Cartoons"
```

I prefer the solution where you just use a folder without spaces if you are going to be doing this often, as those arguments are quite a mouthfull, but for just one or two times, the above is probably easier.

Comment: I can not modify Program Files to Program_Files

Comment: I succeed with this, thanks, I moved this file: Cartoons.keystore in other folder

Comment: I don't use folder with spaces for development.There must be something else as well.

Comment: Just put quotes around the filename.