# Playscape Publishing Kit. failed to sign apk

Tags: unity-game-engine, playscape

Unable to build the project with Playscape Publishing Kit v1.11 on a Mac.

**An error occured while applying post-build logic: failed to sign apk**

Log:

```
AndroidSDKTools:

    root          : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx
    tools         : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/tools
    platform-tools: /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools
    build-tools   : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.1

    adb      : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/platform-tools/adb
    aapt     : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt
    zipalign : /Users/zombie/Documents/android-sdk-macosx/build-tools/22.0.1/zipalign

AndroidJavaTools:
    java     : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

Updating ProjectSettings/QualitySettings.asset - GUID: 00000000000000009000000000000000...
 done. [Time: 3.979047 ms] 

----- Total AssetImport time: 0.035828s, AssetImport time: 0.016885s, Asset hashing: 0.000000s [0 B, 0.000000 mb/s]

Platform assembly: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/lib/mono/2.0/I18N.dll (this message is harmless)
Platform assembly: /Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/Frameworks/Mono/lib/mono/2.0/I18N.West.dll (this message is harmless)
dex2jar /var/folders/nl/rrrmq6m95fd_5ttjk3bnpbth0000gn/T/306jsssc.zmb./classes.dex -> /var/folders/nl/rrrmq6m95fd_5ttjk3bnpbth0000gn/T/vw1vuwf7.9jq.jar
Only one alias can be specified
[PS-Warn] process failed with error 
Please type jarsigner -help for usage

UnityEngine.Debug:Internal_Log(Int32, String, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogWarning(Object)
Playscape.Internal.L:W(String, Object[]) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Internal/L.cs:43)
Playscape.Editor.UnityDebugLogger:W(String, Object[]) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/UnityDebugLogger.cs:38)
Playscape.Editor.AndroidApkCreator:runProcessWithCommand(String, String) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/AndroidApkCreator.cs:515)
Playscape.Editor.AndroidApkCreator:signApk(String) (at Assets/Plugins/Playscape/Editor/AndroidApkCreator.cs:444)
```

Comment: This stack might help:  

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748089/jarsigner-only-one-alias-can-be-specified

Comment: Vlad, Can you provide the arguments with which jarsigner was called?